# How to use javascript to create a custom window other than create a panel with Add-on SDK

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, popup, firefox-addon, customization

Now I'm working on a firefox extension which can show some javascript dialog according the web page action.

I have the chrome extension edition code and it works well.
**It's main workflow is that when I click the extension icon then it will pop out a specific javascript dialog(using [TINYBOX](http://sandbox.scriptiny.com/tinybox2/)) according the web page content.** So I find it's hard for me when I try to do the same stuff in firefox addon.In chrome,the message api is simple and easy to understand.But in firefox addon, I'm often mess up by the page-mod,panel,work and so on.

Now, I try to do like this:

- when I click the firefox extension icon, it will send a message(include the src of main html) to content script;
- then the relative method in the content script use the message to pop up the dialog(use TINYBOX).
- So the page can display but without css and js(because the style and js links in the main html are invalid). So somebody has done this kind of work before? Or
  just give me some tips.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Main.js[Content Script]

```
var workers = [];
var widget = widgets.Widget({
     id: "my-link",
     label: "my-page",
     contentURL: self.data.url('mypage.ico')//,
     //emit the click event
     contentScript: 'self.port.emit('icon-click', 'icon clicked')'  
});

function detachWorker(worker, workerArray) {
   var index = workerArray.indexOf(worker);
   if(index != -1) {
       workerArray.splice(index, 1);
   }
}

var pageMod = require('sdk/page-mod').PageMod({
     include: ['https://my-page.com'],
     //pass the click event to page Script
     contentScript: 'self.port.on("icon-click", function()
           {document.defaultView.postMessage({ action:"icon-clicked", msg: "my message", "https://my-page.com"})
     })',
     onAttach: function(worker) {
         workers.push(worker); 
         worker.on('detach', function () {
               detachWorker(this, workers);
         });
     }
});

//pass event to worker's content script
widget.port.on('icon-click', function(){
    //use for each on workers
    worker[0].port.emit("icon-click", 'icon clicked');
});
```

Now, In your page script listen for postMessage

```
window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
     //include all the dialog libs/resources/css in page  
     var data = event.data;
      if(data.action === 'icon-clicked'){
       showDialog(data.msg);
      }

  }, false);
```

Comment: You may misunderstand my question.My point is about the last one **the page can display but without css and js(because the style and js links in the main html are invalid).** .I can't import the local html file normally.